# Unity game on iOS freezes and lags, but everything is fine on Android

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store

please advise, there is a problem with sound and freezing on the final build for iOS in APP STORE. There is an app with a medium amount of sounds that uses a microphone. I put it on Android and everything works fine, but when I put it on the App Store it started to freeze. The sound started lagging 2/3 of the way through the playback along with the game. When I test on Mac in Unity, on Windows in Unity and on Android there is no such thing. I transferred to mac via flash drive from windows and on mac. When I imported the project for the first time, I seem to remember there was a warning about sounds of some sort, but I closed it immediately and didn't notice it. Also on iOS for some reason very quiet sounds, not like on Android, there you have to turn the speaker to maximum to be normal. What do you think could be the problem?

Video of gameplay on Android Google Play: https://youtube.com/shorts/botUYzAwqBA
Video of gampeplay on App Store IOS: https://youtube.com/shorts/xdN6WRM0nWs

My configuration: Unity: 2021.3.31f1 AdMob: 8.5.2 Xcode: 15 MacOS: MacOS 14 latest BaseSDK: IOS Architecture: Arm64 Ruby: 3.2.2 CocoaPods: 1.13.0
[image: Function with freeze in game]
[image: lag]
[image: Update function on 1 of the scripts]
[image: I think its a function with no freeze in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi4AS.png)